# Does the order matter when checking if a string isn't null and also isn't empty?

Tags: c#, string, null, conditional-statements

I was watching a tutorial about Ternary Operators in C# and the teacher said you should check if the string isn't null first, but didn't explain why. I tried checking if the string wasn't empty first and got the same result as him, so does the it matter?

```
public class TernaryChallenge : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string playerName;
    void OnDisable()
    {
        string name = (playerName != "" && playerName != null) ? "Hello " + playerName : "Hello Player 1!";
        Debug.Log(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that `playerName` did not have some non null value when you ran the above code?  If it were null, I think your code would fail.

Comment: Simple answer yes. When using the && operator, the second condition will not evaluate if the first fails. The reason for the check is that evaluating a null pointer will cause an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter in this case whether you check for empty or null first. You can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method instead and merge two conditions:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(playerName) ? Hello " + playerName : "Hello Player 1!";
```

The order would matter if you were accessing a property of the string, for example:

```
if(playerName.Length < 10 && playerName != null)
```

This will fail if `playerName` is null because you are trying to access `Length` property on a null object. The correct way to check would be:

```
if(playerName != null && playerName.Length < 10)
```

Or you can shorten it using C#'s [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
if(playerName?.Length < 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate it a lot. You're doing God's work my dude.

Answer (score 1):

It can only matter, if you are calling a member method on your string field, As if it is null, you will get a null reference exception. 
In this case of yours you can check for either null or empty in any orderes.

I would also recommend using the built in string.IsNullOrEmpty() method. See the following methods, that are written based on your code, and also the unit tests.

```
   public class TernaryChallenge
    {
        public string playerName;
        public string OnDisable1()
        {
            string name = (playerName != "" && playerName != null) ? "Hello " + 
            playerName : "Hello Player 1!";
            return name;
        }

        public string OnDisable2()
        {
            string name = (playerName != null && playerName != "") ? "Hello " + 
            playerName : "Hello Player 1!";
            return name;
        }

        public string OnDisable3()
        {
            string name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(playerName) ? "Hello " + playerName : 
            "Hello Player 1!";
            return name;
        }

[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var ternaryChallenge = new TernaryChallenge();

            string actual = ternaryChallenge.OnDisable1();
            string expected = "Hello Player 1!";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, ignoreCase: false);

            actual = ternaryChallenge.OnDisable2();
            expected = "Hello Player 1!";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, ignoreCase: false);

            actual = ternaryChallenge.OnDisable3();
            expected = "Hello Player 1!";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, ignoreCase: false);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            var ternaryChallenge = new TernaryChallenge
            {
                playerName = null
            };

            string actual = ternaryChallenge.OnDisable1();
            string expected = "Hello Player 1!";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, ignoreCase: false);

            actual = ternaryChallenge.OnDisable2();
            expected = "Hello Player 1!";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, ignoreCase: false);

            actual = ternaryChallenge.OnDisable3();
            expected = "Hello Player 1!";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, ignoreCase: false);
        }
```

Comment: Kinda went overboard with the unit testing... but a correct answer nonetheless...